# Negate set in combination with negative lookahead

Tags: java, regex, regex-look-ahead

I have this regex `((\.)|(\),)) (([^\.:]+)):` to get values between a `.` and `:`
The problems is that I don't want to consider the dots inside a parenthesis. My idea was to add a negative lookahead with something like `(?!.*\(,)` but no success so far.

Here is an example of text:

```
Simple text (Example with . inside), The key: Value. Another key: sfdfd.
```

The text i want to extract is `The key` and `Another key`

How could i solve this?

Comment: How could a regular expression starting with a point (i.e. `\.`) ever match the part "The key" in your sample text?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Ok fair point, I have updated the question.

Comment: @user16320675 It is correct

Comment: @user16320675 Since in your example there is no comma after ) it should extract all: example, First (..inside) key

Comment: You say _"between a `.` and `:`"_, but it looks like you want it between `:` and `.`? Can't you just exclude `()`? Like so: [`:([^()]+?)\.`](https://regex101.com/r/6dN9GY/1) ?

Comment: @TedLyngmo no, not really. The text after `:` could contain dates, amounts and also ()

Comment: @FabioPiunti I see. And won't they have `.` too? Perhaps you should make a list of (complicated) examples and what you want to extract from each?

Comment: What is the rule to match only `The key` as it is preceded by a comma and `)`

Comment: @FabioPiunti After your question update ... it is still very unclear. You describe a part of your requirement as _match a dot but do not match dots inside brackets_. Yet, you want to match the key `The key`, although there is no regular dot in front of that.

Comment: A little criticism: Your question text (i.e. your requirement) is written in a very vague style. But it is not possible to develop code in a vague style. So, first you should really phrase your requirements in a clear and concise way. Maybe also with several matching and non-matching examples. Then you (first) might be able to derive a good regular expression. If not, then we (second) might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have guaranties on parentheses parity - it would be impossible to solve:

```
"Simple text ))(Example with (. ((inside), The key: Value. Another key: sfdfd."
```

However if you have such guaranty, e.g. `single level only + parity`, then you can solve it in two steps

- remove parts with parentheses,
- extract your data

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Simple text (Example with . inside), The key: Value. Another key: sfdfd.";
    System.out.println(Stream.of(s
        .replaceAll("\\([^()]*\\)", "")
        .split("(?:^|:)[^.,]*[.,]\\s*")
    ).filter(it -> !it.isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

Stdout:

```
[The key, Another key]
```